# How do you split all of a certain character in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, split

```
string="i-want-all-dashes-split"

print(split(string,"-"))
```

So I want the output to be:

```
string=(I,-,want,-,all,-,dashes,-,split)
```

I basically want to partition all the "-"'s.

Comment: `import re; print(','.join(re.split('(-)', string)))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> import re
>>> string = "i-want-all-dashes-split"

>>> string.split('-')                 # without the dashes
['i', 'want', 'all', 'dashes', 'split']

>>> re.split('(-)', string)           # with the dashes
['i', '-', 'want', '-', 'all', '-', 'dashes', '-', 'split']

>>> ','.join(re.split('(-)', string)) # as a string joined by commas
'i,-,want,-,all,-,dashes,-,split'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function too:

**Code:**

```
def split_keep(s, delim):

    s = s.split(delim)
    result = []

    for i, n in enumerate(s):
        result.append(n)
        if i == len(s)-1: pass
        else: result.append(delim)

    return result
```

**Usage:**

```
split_keep("i-want-all-dashes-split", "-")
```

**Output:**

```
['i', '-', 'want', '-', 'all', '-', 'dashes', '-', 'split']
```

Comment: That's not quite working. In like 8 you put d and I'm pretty sure you meant to put delim, But after editing that and putting that into my code, the output is ['i', 'want', '-', 'all', '-', 'dashes', '-', 'split', '-']. It's moving the first dash to the last part of string,

Comment: Oops! Just fixed it.. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
string="i-want-all-dashes-split"

print 'string='+str(string.split('-')).replace('[','(').replace(']',')').replace(' ','-,')

>>>string=('i',-,'want',-,'all',-,'dashes',-,'split')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the split function from str class:

```
text = "i-want-all-dashes-split"
splitted = text.split('-')
```

The value of **splitted** be a list like the one bellow:

```
['i', 'want', 'all', 'dashes', 'split']
```

If you want the output as a tuple, do it like in the code bellow:

```
t = tuple(splitted)
('i', 'want', 'all', 'dashes', 'split')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string="i-want-all-dashes-split"
print(string.slip('-'))
# Output:
['i', 'want', 'all', 'dashes', 'split']
```

string.split()
Inside the () you can put your delimiter ('-'), if you don't put anything it would be (',') by default.
You can make a function:

```
def spliter(string, delimiter=','): # delimiter have a default argument (',')
    string = string.split(delimiter)
    result = []
    for x, y in enumerate(string):
        result.append(y)
        if x != len(string)-1: result.append(delimiter)
    return result
```

Output:

```
['i', '-', 'want', '-', 'all', '-', 'dashes', '-', 'split']
```